# ffplay seek function

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure out how the seek function using the left/right arrows in ffplay works
i went inside thier open source code and tried to change the values from 10,-10 to different values so i can see if the seek moves correctly but after few attempts i saw that the movie postion after using either left or right arrow isnt moving to exactly the value i specified.

For example, if i used the default value 10, and the movie was on 00:10:00, after pressing the right arrow which suppose to move the movie to 00:20:00 i got something like 00:21:35 and it was not constant.

I tried that on varity of movies and got diffrenet results each time.

Anyone has any idea what i'm doing wrong? or can explain how the seek works in ffplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video seeking precision depends on a variety of factors, but mainly PTS, DTS, and GOP Length. a GOP (Group of Pictures) starts with an I frame (or fixed picture). When you seek, it's just probably trying to find the closest I frame that has a PTS (Presentation Timestamp) grater than 20. What complicates things even further is that not all videos have a fixed GOP length (also called closed GOP) so seeking 10 seconds further in different positions will not always add 11.35 seconds.

Check out this article on GOP
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures